# Python poplib: retrieving body of the email result to NONE

Tags: python, python-3.x, poplib

I can get the subject of the email however the body always result to NONE. Tried following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908472/how-to-receive-mail-using-python) but all the suggestions end up the same. The body still prints as NONE.

```
import poplib
from email import parser
pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('my_email.com')
pop_conn.pass_('my_password')
#Get messages from server:
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
# Concat message pieces:
messages = ['\n'.join(map(bytes.decode, mssg[1])) for mssg in messages]
#Parse message intom an email object:
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]

for message in messages:
    print (message['subject'])
    print (message['body'])
    print (message.get_payload())
pop_conn.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import poplib
from email import parser
pop_conn = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_conn.user('my_email.com')
pop_conn.pass_('my_password')
#Get messages from server:
messages = [pop_conn.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_conn.list()[1]) + 1)]
# Concat message pieces:
messages = ['\n'.join(map(bytes.decode, mssg[1])) for mssg in messages]
#Parse message intom an email object:
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]

for message in messages:
    print (message['subject'])
    print (message['from'])
    for part in message.walk():
        if part.get_content_type():
            body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            print(body)
pop_conn.quit()
```

This did the trick. However it prints a straight line. Anybody know how to print per line if the body of the message is long?