# Is it possible to use Python to send an email to recipients in a PST file, and then remove any email addresses that bounce-back?

Tags: python, list, smtp, append

I hope that's understandable.

I have a .pst file of around 900 email addresses, i wanted to send a generic email to those recipients and whichever ones bounced back to append that list and remove the ones that are no longer active.

Before i attempt this, i wanted to see if this type of things was possible?

Comment: Anything is possible....

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/353/

Comment: You should always attempt every project, if you have time

Comment: a more useful series of questions might be [how to send an email using python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) and [how to recieve mail using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908472/how-to-receive-mail-using-python)