# Trigger python script or command line sent by server on the client PC via email

Tags: python

I have source codes with socket and functions are already developed. Now my teacher want me to gain remote access to another computer through gmail or other mails. I didn't know where to begin with so I need helps for my assignments.

The result I think it is like server send a mail to client. client open the mail & the code in the mail automatic run and execute.

Answer (score 0):

[Firstly you need to have access to reading emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908472/how-to-receive-mail-using-python)

[Secondly you need to execute the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

[Thirdly you need to send back the output through email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python)

Your question is not very clear try making it more understandable so that we can help you better.

- Jerome :)